# Why is margin-top counting from the top of the website and not the element above?

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

I think I'm missing a very important css-rule to make sure when I'm using margin-top for example, things like my footer and H1 element beneath the image won't recognize the image and start using the margin-top from there.

Example: I have to use margin-top: 50px; to get the H1 element beneath the image, otherwise the text will be displayed ON the image instead of beneath.

HOW IT IS WORKING RIGHT NOW WHEN USING h1 {MARGIN-TOP: 50px;}:

```css
main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;

}

/*navigation*/

#navigation {
    font-family: 'Aller Display';
    color: black;

}

#logo {
    float: left;
    width: 229px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 52px;
    margin-top: 0;
    clear: both;

}

#mobilemenu {
    display: none;
}

#navigation_list {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#navigation_list li {

    display: inline-block;

}

#navigation_list li a {
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 75px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;

}

#navigation_list li a:hover {

    color: #f07c00;

}

#rightnav {
    margin-right: 22px;
}

/*overzicht gerechten*/
h1.overzichtger {

    font-family: 'Aller Bold';
    margin-left: 150px;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 50px;


}

div.centerimg {

    text-align: center;

}

img.imgoverzichtgerechtlinks {
    float: left;
    width: 470px;
    height: 176px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

img.imgoverzichtgerechtrechts {

    float: right;
    width: 470px;
    height: 176px;
    overflow: hidden;


}


/*footer*/

footer {

    font-family: 'Aller Bold';
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 21px;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #f07c00;
    color: black;
    line-height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
}

#test {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
```

```html
<main>

    <nav id="navigation">
        <img src="logo.jpg" id="logo">
        <a id="mobilemenu" class="menu_button" href="#footer_nav" onclick="toggleNav(); return false;">&#9776;  MENU</a>
        <ul id="navigation_list" role="navigation">
            <li><a href=#>Nieuws</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Info</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Bezienswaardigheden</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Keuken</a></li>
            <li id="rightnav"><a href=#>Steden</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

        <br> <br>



        <img src="geroverzicht1.jpg" class="imgoverzichtgerechtlinks">
        <img src="geroverzicht2.jpg" class="imgoverzichtgerechtrechts">
        <br><br>
        <div class="test">
        <h1 class="overzichtger">Pepernoten</h1>
            </div>



    <footer>
        <div id="test">
        </div>
    </footer>


</main>
```

No idea what to do anymore, I've been checking on other topics on stackoverflow regarding the same problem and I've added overflow: hidden to both pictures because they were floating.

Comment: Can you extract only the portion of the code necessary to replicate the problem? And then, don't show the entire block again if you're changing just one line - just mention it.

Comment: @light I removed the unnecessary block of code because I indeed mentioned it before and I tried to remove as much as possible of my code which wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are floating the two images above the h1. When you float an element, it is "taken out of the document flow", and tells the rendering engine to display the subsequent elements "next to it".

So what happens is that your `<div class="test">` (the one containing the `h1`) tries to be next to the two images you have floated.

The possible solutions:

1. Set `<div class="test">` to `clear:both`, which is basically instructing the browser to not put anything beside it, no matter what any preceding floated elements say.
2. Don't use floats. Set your images to `display: inline-block`, which seems to be what you are trying to do. Don't forget to set `vertical-align` too. This was partly the reason why `display:inline-block` was invented - float layout can be confusing and difficult to manage.

Additionally, do try to not use `<br>` in your code to create space. And also note that `<main>` tag is not supported in all browsers.